# Upgrading Windows service using Inno Setup

Tags: installation, inno-setup

I've created a basic Windows service installation using Inno Setup. both install and uninstall works properly.

However, I'm having issues with the upgrade procedure.

In order to upgrade the service executable it is necessary to stop the service, and only after the service is completely stopped can the updated executables be placed in the target folder.

How can I execute a service-stop command and wait for the service to be completely stopped before the file deployment step is initiated?

Answer (score 21):

The code below comes from the following page:
http://www.vincenzo.net/isxkb/index.php?title=Service_-_Functions_to_Start%2C_Stop%2C_Install%2C_Remove_a_Service

However, I had to apply a minor fix to make it work.

> Note that I originally posted this answer in 2010. The code at
>   the page above was updated in 2011, so it might be worth a visit.

I use this code in my installer, as an `#include`. It is compiled in Inno Setup **ANSI**.
It may work for the Unicode version of Inno Setup by replacing `A@` with `W@` in all `external` declarations (thank you JeroenWiertPluimers for pointing that out).

Also note that the `StartService` and `StopService` just send a start/stop signal, but do not wait for the service to be in the running of stopped state. You can construct code that would wait for the service to be running, using the using `IsServiceRunning` in conjunction with the Pascal Script `Sleep()` function. Or just `Sleep()` a predefined number of seconds.

The code implements these functions:

```pascal
function IsServiceInstalled(ServiceName: string) : boolean;
function IsServiceRunning(ServiceName: string) : boolean;
function InstallService(FileName, ServiceName, DisplayName, Description : string;ServiceType,StartType :cardinal) : boolean;
function RemoveService(ServiceName: string) : boolean;
function StartService(ServiceName: string) : boolean;
function StopService(ServiceName: string) : boolean;
function SetupService(service, port, comment: string) : boolean;
```

The actual code:

```pascal
type
    SERVICE_STATUS = record
        dwServiceType               : cardinal;
        dwCurrentState              : cardinal;
        dwControlsAccepted          : cardinal;
        dwWin32ExitCode             : cardinal;
        dwServiceSpecificExitCode   : cardinal;
        dwCheckPoint                : cardinal;
        dwWaitHint                  : cardinal;
    end;
    HANDLE = cardinal;

const
    SERVICE_QUERY_CONFIG        = $1;
    SERVICE_CHANGE_CONFIG       = $2;
    SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS        = $4;
    SERVICE_START               = $10;
    SERVICE_STOP                = $20;
    SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS          = $f01ff;
    SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS       = $f003f;
    SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS   = $10;
    SERVICE_WIN32_SHARE_PROCESS = $20;
    SERVICE_WIN32               = $30;
    SERVICE_INTERACTIVE_PROCESS = $100;
    SERVICE_BOOT_START          = $0;
    SERVICE_SYSTEM_START        = $1;
    SERVICE_AUTO_START          = $2;
    SERVICE_DEMAND_START        = $3;
    SERVICE_DISABLED            = $4;
    SERVICE_DELETE              = $10000;
    SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP        = $1;
    SERVICE_CONTROL_PAUSE       = $2;
    SERVICE_CONTROL_CONTINUE    = $3;
    SERVICE_CONTROL_INTERROGATE = $4;
    SERVICE_STOPPED             = $1;
    SERVICE_START_PENDING       = $2;
    SERVICE_STOP_PENDING        = $3;
    SERVICE_RUNNING             = $4;
    SERVICE_CONTINUE_PENDING    = $5;
    SERVICE_PAUSE_PENDING       = $6;
    SERVICE_PAUSED              = $7;

{ nt based service utilities }
function OpenSCManager(lpMachineName, lpDatabaseName: string; dwDesiredAccess :cardinal): HANDLE;
external 'OpenSCManagerA@advapi32.dll stdcall';

function OpenService(hSCManager :HANDLE;lpServiceName: string; dwDesiredAccess :cardinal): HANDLE;
external 'OpenServiceA@advapi32.dll stdcall';

function CloseServiceHandle(hSCObject :HANDLE): boolean;
external 'CloseServiceHandle@advapi32.dll stdcall';

function CreateService(hSCManager :HANDLE;lpServiceName, lpDisplayName: string;dwDesiredAccess,dwServiceType,dwStartType,dwErrorControl: cardinal;lpBinaryPathName,lpLoadOrderGroup: String; lpdwTagId : cardinal;lpDependencies,lpServiceStartName,lpPassword :string): cardinal;
external 'CreateServiceA@advapi32.dll stdcall';

function DeleteService(hService :HANDLE): boolean;
external 'DeleteService@advapi32.dll stdcall';

function StartNTService(hService :HANDLE;dwNumServiceArgs : cardinal;lpServiceArgVectors : cardinal) : boolean;
external 'StartServiceA@advapi32.dll stdcall';

function ControlService(hService :HANDLE; dwControl :cardinal;var ServiceStatus :SERVICE_STATUS) : boolean;
external 'ControlService@advapi32.dll stdcall';

function QueryServiceStatus(hService :HANDLE;var ServiceStatus :SERVICE_STATUS) : boolean;
external 'QueryServiceStatus@advapi32.dll stdcall';

function QueryServiceStatusEx(hService :HANDLE;ServiceStatus :SERVICE_STATUS) : boolean;
external 'QueryServiceStatus@advapi32.dll stdcall';

function GetLastError() : cardinal;
external 'GetLastError@kernel32.dll stdcall';

function OpenServiceManager() : HANDLE;
begin
    if UsingWinNT() = true then begin
        Result := OpenSCManager('','',SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);
        if Result = 0 then
            MsgBox('the servicemanager is not available', mbError, MB_OK)
    end
    else begin
            MsgBox('only nt based systems support services', mbError, MB_OK)
            Result := 0;
    end
end;

function IsServiceInstalled(ServiceName: string) : boolean;
var
    hSCM    : HANDLE;
    hService: HANDLE;
begin
    hSCM := OpenServiceManager();
    Result := false;
    if hSCM <> 0 then begin
        hService := OpenService(hSCM,ServiceName,SERVICE_QUERY_CONFIG);
        if hService <> 0 then begin
            Result := true;
            CloseServiceHandle(hService)
        end;
        CloseServiceHandle(hSCM)
    end
end;

function InstallService(FileName, ServiceName, DisplayName, Description : string;ServiceType,StartType :cardinal) : boolean;
var
    hSCM    : HANDLE;
    hService: HANDLE;
begin
    hSCM := OpenServiceManager();
    Result := false;
    if hSCM <> 0 then begin
        hService := CreateService(hSCM,ServiceName,DisplayName,SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS,ServiceType,StartType,0,FileName,'',0,'','','');
        if hService <> 0 then begin
            Result := true;
            { Win2K & WinXP supports additional description text for services }
            if Description<> '' then
                RegWriteStringValue(HKLM,'System\CurrentControlSet\Services\' + ServiceName,'Description',Description);
            CloseServiceHandle(hService)
        end;
        CloseServiceHandle(hSCM)
    end
end;

function RemoveService(ServiceName: string) : boolean;
var
    hSCM    : HANDLE;
    hService: HANDLE;
begin
    hSCM := OpenServiceManager();
    Result := false;
    if hSCM <> 0 then begin
        hService := OpenService(hSCM,ServiceName,SERVICE_DELETE);
        if hService <> 0 then begin
            Result := DeleteService(hService);
            CloseServiceHandle(hService)
        end;
        CloseServiceHandle(hSCM)
    end
end;

function StartService(ServiceName: string) : boolean;
var
    hSCM    : HANDLE;
    hService: HANDLE;
begin
    hSCM := OpenServiceManager();
    Result := false;
    if hSCM <> 0 then begin
        hService := OpenService(hSCM,ServiceName,SERVICE_START);
        if hService <> 0 then begin
            Result := StartNTService(hService,0,0);
            CloseServiceHandle(hService)
        end;
        CloseServiceHandle(hSCM)
    end;
end;

function StopService(ServiceName: string) : boolean;
var
    hSCM    : HANDLE;
    hService: HANDLE;
    Status  : SERVICE_STATUS;
begin
    hSCM := OpenServiceManager();
    Result := false;
    if hSCM <> 0 then begin
        hService := OpenService(hSCM,ServiceName,SERVICE_STOP);
        if hService <> 0 then begin
            Result := ControlService(hService,SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP,Status);
            CloseServiceHandle(hService)
        end;
        CloseServiceHandle(hSCM)
    end;
end;

function IsServiceRunning(ServiceName: string) : boolean;
var
    hSCM    : HANDLE;
    hService: HANDLE;
    Status  : SERVICE_STATUS;
begin
    hSCM := OpenServiceManager();
    Result := false;
    if hSCM <> 0 then begin
        hService := OpenService(hSCM,ServiceName,SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS);
        if hService <> 0 then begin
            if QueryServiceStatus(hService,Status) then begin
                Result :=(Status.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_RUNNING)
            end;
            CloseServiceHandle(hService)
            end;
        CloseServiceHandle(hSCM)
    end
end;
```

Comment: I inherited some code that looks just like your answer. They didn't mention the source nor *ANSI* so it took me a while to realise the `ERROR_INVALID_NAME` a.k.a. 123 (0x7B) error thrown by `OpenSCManager` could be solved by replacing `A@` with `W@` in all `external` declarations as I was running Inno Setup *Unicode*.

Comment: I used this solution but with the most recent version of Windows 10 I got this error: "the service manager is not avilable"

Answer (score 8):

As of Inno Setup 5.5.0, the [CloseApplications](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_setup_closeapplications.htm) and [RestartApplications](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_setup_restartapplications.htm) directives are now available. These options will detect files in use and shut down the applications using them.

Comment: CloseApplications and RestartApplications use the [Windows Restart Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373524.aspx), and it supports GUI, Console and **service** applications.

Comment: I couldn't get CloseApplications to work for a service - not sure why

Answer (score 5):

There are two parts to this:

1. **How can an installer created with Inno Setup start and stop services, how can it create and delete them, how can it change their startup mode?**
   By using the helper functions provided in this [collection of routines](https://www.sandon.it/2011/02/25/inno-setup-library-to-manage-windows-services/) written for exactly this purpose. It is written for the Ansi version of Inno Setup, so changes will be necessary to the API function imports and the `PChar` parameter types, but it should get you started.
2. **How can an existing service be stopped before the new file version is copied?**
   You have basically two ways of doing this. You would use Pascal scripting to execute the functions linked to above to stop the service, you just need to decide whether to do it in one of the event functions, or whether to do it in a custom function that will be called via the `Check` parameter of the file entry for the service executable. I would definitely do it in the former, so you can check whether the service was successfully stopped, and prohibit the installation from actually starting when this failed.
   You should look into the `CurStepChanged()` and `NextButtonClick()` event functions, depending on whether you possibly need to prevent the next step. The Inno Setup examples show the use of both functions.

Comment: Your answer is still relevant, would you mind editing the dead link after 11 years :P

Comment: @Koder101: With only a short delay I did just that...

Answer (score 3):

I am using a batch file that stops, uninstalls, installs and starts a given service, i just call the batchfile using innosetup after all files have been copied.

```
[Run]
Filename: "{app}\Scripts\installwindowsService.bat"; Parameters: "{app}"; Flags: runhidden
```

I put the following commands in my batch file

```
net stop MyService

%SYSTEMROOT%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\installutil.exe /u MyService.exe 

%SYSTEMROOT%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\installutil.exe  MyService.exe /unattended

net start MyService
```

It works like a charm and is very simple. can be used for a first time install or for an update. Hope it helps you.

Comment: It's too late to comment but worth if someone visiting in 2021 or later - This will not work in case the service is already installed and running and when you re-run the setup. The service file will remain locked and will not be replaced with the new file.