# Inno Setup .NET DLL call works in 64-bit, fails in 32-bit

Tags: c#, .net, inno-setup, dllexport

I wrote a simple interface into the SQL SMO library, so I can stop and start a SQL Server during installation from Inno Setup scripts. My development machine is a 64-bit processor machine. The managed code is written in Visual Basic using DllExport for .Net, targeting .NET 4.0 and compiling for the x86 platform. I am using Inno Setup 5.5.9 Unicode version.

The setup executable works fine on my development machine and other 64-bit processors I have tried. When I run the executable on a 32-bit processor system I get an error:

> External Exception E0434352

Which is pretty unhelpful and generic. Both systems are Windows 10, but I have tried it on other Windows versions also and 64-bit works and 32-bit doesn't. So what have I done to hamper running on 32 bit?

Inno Setup code:

```pascal
[Files]
Source: "fiSqlSmoLib2\bin\x86\Debug\fiSqlSmoLib2.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; \
    Flags: nocompression 32bit

[Code]

function StartSql(machineName, sqlServerName: AnsiString): Integer;
external 'StartSql@files:fiSqlSmoLib2.dll stdcall setuponly delayload';

function StopSql(machineName, sqlServerName: AnsiString): Integer;
external 'StopSql@files:fiSqlSmoLib2.dll stdcall setuponly delayload';

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
var
  SQLresultCode : Integer;
  Computer : String;
  SQLServer : String;
begin
  Computer := GetComputerNameString;
  SQLServer := 'FACTORYINSITE';

  try
    SQLresultCode := StopSql(Computer, SQLServer);
  except
    ShowExceptionMessage;
    exit;
  end;
  try
    SQLresultCode := StartSql(Computer, SQLServer);
  except
    ShowExceptionMessage;
    exit;
  end;
end;
```

Visual Basic code:

```vb
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Wmi
Imports RGiesecke.DllExport

Public Class fiSqlSmo

    <DllExport("StartSql", CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
    Public Shared Function StartSql(<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)> machineName As String, <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)> sqlServerName As String) As Integer
        Dim mc As ManagedComputer
        Dim Svc As Service
        Dim svcState As ServiceState
        Try
            mc = New ManagedComputer(machineName)
            Svc = mc.Services("MSSQL$" + sqlServerName)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return ServiceState.Unknown
        End Try
        Try
            svcState = Svc.ServiceState
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return ServiceState.Unknown
        End Try
        If (Svc.ServiceState <> ServiceState.Running) Then
            Svc.Start()
        End If
        Return svcState
    End Function

    <DllExport("StopSql", CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
    Public Shared Function StopSql(<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)> machineName As String, <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)> sqlServerName As String) As Integer
        Dim mc As ManagedComputer
        Dim Svc As Service
        Dim svcState As ServiceState
        Try
            mc = New ManagedComputer(machineName)
            Svc = mc.Services("MSSQL$" + sqlServerName)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return ServiceState.Unknown
        End Try
        Try
            svcState = Svc.ServiceState
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return ServiceState.Unknown
        End Try
        If (Svc.ServiceState = ServiceState.Running) Then
            Svc.Stop()
        End If
        Return svcState
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure SMO is not installed by default, is it available on the machines where it fails?  does your code work from a console app on those machines? You do not need SMO to start/stop the MSSQL service you can simply use `ServiceController` or remove any .Net dependencies by [using Pascal Script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456987/upgrading-windows-service-using-inno-setup)

Comment: Or try to catch and log any exception in VB.NET code for debug the problem.

Comment: I believe that SMO is installed on the test machines, but that is a good suggestion to check. I'll try a console app as well.

The SQL server will be on different node than the setup code, or possibly on Azure so I think SMO may be the best method. In the full installation I also log into the SQL server and run scripts, which is why I need to ensure that it is running.

Comment: In the .net code that I posted I removed the logging statements from within the catch blocks for clarity. There were no errors logged by .net calls which makes me wonder about my calling methods.

Comment: What happens if you write another VB program and try using your library from it with `Declare Function`?

Comment: Getting your program to run on any other machine tends to be the other 90% of the project.  You cannot get there until you write an event handler for the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException event.  It is *never* optional.  So you'll **know** why your app doesn't run.  And so you can write a question that helps us help you instead of us having to post arbitrary guesses.

Comment: Thanks Hans, I will try to get at the exception underlying the error.

Comment: To test handling unhandled events I added the following code:

    Dim currentDomain As AppDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
     AddHandler currentDomain.UnhandledException, AddressOf MyHandler
    Dim infinity As Integer = 42
    infinity /= 0

The exception is handled by inno setup and not my handler.

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be the version of SMO assemblies used. The setup program that works was linked against the SLQ 2016 version of SMO, while the machines on which it failed only had SQL 2008 R2 installed. It seems to be coincidental that the machines with an older version are 32 bit.

Rebuilding the .NET code to reference the oldest SMO version causes it to work on all machines.